# Is there any PHP transpilers from 5.4 to 5.2 for old servers?

Tags: php, porting, legacy

Sometimes I have to deal with clients' old servers with only PHP 5.2 installed. They have old projects there and upgrading is a problem. But sometimes I want to use a library with namespaces or new array literals.

Is there a tool to transpile code to run it on an old server? Just like babel.js for javascript.

Before transpiling:

```
$russian_words = ["Matrioshka", "Balalaika", "Kalashnikov"];
```

After:

```
$russian_words = array("Matrioshka", "Balalaika", "Kalashnikov");
```

And also for some differently configurated servers:

```
<?="And the answer is: $mystery"; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php echo "And the answer is:" . $mystery; ?>
```

Comment: Solution: Run each app on its own VM

Comment: Also considering PHPs track record with holes, I wouldn't use an old unpatched version on the net

Comment: @jurgemaister but all they usually have is a VPS with other projects just running from different users. Or may be I just try to run a VM inside a VM...Any possible pitfalls here? :)

Comment: Put the "old projects" into a VM, upgrade the main server to PHP 5.5 and develop for the future, not for the past. I see why "clients" do not want to upgrade their infrastructure, but that leads to even more problems in the future and more costs. It is also bad practice and endangers security of everyone who has contact with these lecacy chunks of code. Choose your weapons wisely, you cannot win a war nowadays with a sword, just because you client is to lazy to buy a handgun. Just sayin.

Comment: @EdeleHere  Just run each project on its own instance. Shared instances are icky.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if there were a transpiler. What you could do is use a build system like gulp or grunt to watch for PHP file changes and run custom search/replace actions, but this could lead to some strange errors.

The problem is that PHP 5.3 brought some pretty big changes and somethings you can do post 5.3 just don't have an equivalent in < 5.3.

The real answer is to implement good tests and, unfortunately don't use third-party components that are incompatible (until you can convince the client that they NEED to get past 5.3 at least).